# NVIDIA driver fail causing Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS login loop

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, kernel, login

My Ubuntu PC got stuck in a login loop due to an error I got from the nvidia driver. I also got this error few times earlier with another pc, however re-installing the driver was solving the problem. However in this case, I am not able to re-install the driver. Normally what I do:

```
sudo service lightdm stop

sudo apt-get purge nvidia*

sudo ./NVIDIA-driver(XXX.XX).run
```

after a successful installation of the nvidia driver

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

and normally it would solve the problem. Even before these steps, when I was asking for `nvidia-smi`, it was not able to detect the gpu in the machine. I am trying to install the new driver, however it also fails during the installation of the kernel.

I use a Tesla C2075 and I have read all the available answers here, however none of them has solved my problem. Please let me know if any further information needed.

Comment: Try `sudo apt install gdm3`, `sudo service lightdm stop` and then `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`. This will install a different display manager that, for me, works with Nvidia cards and proprietary drivers. Unfortunately a lot of Nvidia cards/drivers just seem to dislike lightdm so I'm not sure there's a fix, only workarounds.